# How to extract data from XML using node.js

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js

how to extract data from XML type rest API using node.js?

This is the code i used to get data by sending rest api request:

```
//Load the request module
var request = require('request');
//Lets configure and request
request(
    {
        url: 'http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/resources?resource=DEV:Fabrice%20Bellingard:org.codehaus.sonar:sonar&metrics=ncloc,coverage', //URL to hit
        method: 'GET', //Specify the method
        headers: { //We can define headers too
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer( 'admin' + ':'+'admin').toString('base64'),
            'Content-Type': 'MyContentType',
            'Custom-Header': 'Custom Value'
        }
    },
    function(error, response, body){
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            var obj=JSON.parse(response.body);
            console.log(obj.id);
        }
    }
)
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000,function (){
    console.log('port 3000');
}
```

);

When I send the request using a browser, the result appears like:

```
<resources>
 <resource>
 <id>400009</id>
 <key>DEV:Fabrice Bellingard:org.codehaus.sonar:sonar</key>
 <name>SonarQube</name>
 <lname>SonarQube</lname>
 <scope>PRJ</scope>
 <qualifier>DEV_PRJ</qualifier>
 <date>2015-08-04T13:10:57+0000</date>
 <creationDate/>
 <copy>48569</copy>
 <msr>
   <key>ncloc</key>
   <val>879.0</val>
   <frmt_val>879</frmt_val>
 </msr>
 <msr>
   <key>coverage</key>
   <val>81.8</val>
   <frmt_val>81.8%</frmt_val>
 </msr>
</resource>
</resources>
```

I want to extract the *id* and print it on the console using node.js.
How I want to edit the above code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is response.body is in array format, so get the first item in the array and then its `id` value

```
//Load the request module
var request = require('request');
//Lets configure and request
request({

    url: 'http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/resources?resource=DEV:Fabrice%20Bellingard:org.codehaus.sonar:sonar&metrics=ncloc,coverage', //URL to hit

    method: 'GET', //Specify the method
    headers: { //We can define headers too
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer('admin' + ':' + 'admin').toString('base64'),
        'Content-Type': 'MyContentType',
        'Custom-Header': 'Custom Value'
    }
}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        var arr = JSON.parse(response.body);
        var obj = arr[0];
        console.log(obj.id);
    }
})
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('port 3000');;
});
```

Comment: @Quentin no... when it is ran using nodejs it is giving json output... but in browser xml o/p is coming... it is giving `400009` in the console

Comment: The question has a big, fat, red herring in it. (sigh)